# How to simplify a loop over two variable lists

Tags: loops, regression, stata

I have a dataset with three time series observations for 3 stocks, and variables r and v for each. My data is organized in wide form, i.e. I have `r1`, `r2`, `r3` and `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, with time index `t`. I need to use a loop (not `statsby`/other long form solutions) to run three regressions, i.e. `r1 v1`, `r2 v2` and `r3 v3`. So far I have only managed to write the following:

```
tsset t
foreach r of varlist r1 r2 r3 {
  foreach v of varlist v1 v2 v3 {
    reg `r' `v'
  }
}
```

This obviously runs 9 regressions where only 3 are needed. How do I simplify this loop to only run the regressions I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one loop, so don't program two.

```
forval j = 1/3 {
    reg r`j' v`j' 
}
```

The trick is to see what varies: it's the suffix `1 2 3`. `r` and `v` are needed every time around the loop, so can be wired into the code as constants.